# Query to select all dates (when some are missing in a non-related table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
absen (date, time, id_user)
calendar (datefield)
employee (id_user, name, department, address)

Table absen example:

date        time       user_id
2015/01/02  08:00:00   00600320
2015/01/03  08:25:00   00600320
2015/01/05  08:10:00   00600320
.
.
2015/01/31  09:00:00   00600320
```

I'm looking for a result like this:

```
date         time      user_id
2015/01/01   --:--:--  00600320
2015/01/02   08:00:00  00600320
2015/01/03   08:25:00  00600320
2015/01/04   --:--:--  00600320
2015/01/05   08:10:00  00600320
.
.
2015/01/31   09:00:00  00600320
```

Comment: *I want select like that* based on what condition/scenario?

Comment: hi... could you post the sql statements you used to create the table along with what you have tried so far to get the query?

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting and improve the title, I hope I conveyed your intent in a proper way.

Comment: Thank you for your attention ... the master of all.
I want to show the absence of data perkaryawan based calendar between 01/01/2015 and 01/31/2015. all data is absent and employees in the show although there who are not absent on that date in the calendar the date fixed in the show. but the data time in the dressing -: -: -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `calendar` table holds all the dates of the month using the `date` data type, and that `absen` uses `date` and `time` then this query might be what you want:

```
select 
    c.datefield, 
    coalesce(cast(a.time as varchar(8)), '--:--:--') as time, 
    e.id_user 
from calendar c
cross join employee e
left join absen a on c.datefield = a.date and e.id_user = a.id_user
where c.datefield between '2015/01/01' and '2015/01/31'
```

The `cross join` between `calendar` and `employee` generates the cross product of the set with dates and the set of employees and the `left join` pulls in the times from `absen` and when for the dates where the time is missing the `coalesce` replaces the missing value with `--:--:--`.

Since the information about your database setup wasn't all clear I guessed a bit.

Comment: I try and will let you know the results. thanks before.

Comment: Thank's a Lot. ur that's cool. ur really really help me MASTER. IT WORK. but delay is to long 17second to generate. how to fast it.